# ¿Cómo pasar multiples valores a un parametro de una funcion de sql?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta función:

```
SELECT *  FROM legaltec.dbo.fu_let_dv_robot_RevTecHistoriaDetalle(56245)
```

Necesito pasarle a esa función múltiples parámetros ejem: **(12334,676868,3874)**. ¿Podrían ayudarme? Por favor.

Esta es la funcion:

```
GO
/****** Objeto:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fu_let_dv_robot_Kilometraje]    Fecha de la secuencia de comandos: 09/24/2019 17:24:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fu_let_dv_robot_Kilometraje](@tseCodigo int) returns @tabla table (
                        FechaKM varchar(10)  
                        ,Kilometraje varchar(20)   
                        ,Fuente varchar(250)
                        ,TipoDato varchar(150)
                        , Anioveh int
                        , Fecha datetime
                        , kilometros int
                        , KilometrajeDudoso int
                        , IdOrigen int
                        , AnioKilometraje int
                        , AutosNuevos int
                        )
AS
BEGIN
```

El problema es que la función recibe un int y no tengo permiso para editar la función...

Comment: Hola @Yusary, te paso un ejemplo de como podrías hacer: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S

Comment: Por favor, no uses el código del artículo sugerido. Eso puede hacer que las consultas se vuelvan hasta 40 veces más lentas.

Comment: Sería bueno saber que hace el código de esa función para poder ayudarte.

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta con el codigo de la funcion

Comment: Pues si no puedes editar la función, te queda invocarla tantas veces como valores necesites procesar en la función.

Comment: @Alfabravo puedes mostrarme como, soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como dice @Alfabravo, si no puedes modificar la función, solo puedes llamarla una vez por cada id. Hay dos maneras de hacerlo

la 1ra es hacerlo manualmente...

```
 SELECT *  FROM legaltec.dbo.fu_let_dv_robot_RevTecHistoriaDetalle(12334)
 union all
 SELECT *  FROM legaltec.dbo.fu_let_dv_robot_RevTecHistoriaDetalle(676868)
 union all
 SELECT *  FROM legaltec.dbo.fu_let_dv_robot_RevTecHistoriaDetalle(3874)
```

Pero como pueden ser muchos id lo puedes hacer con un cursor:

```
    declare @tabla table (
                            FechaKM varchar(10)  
                            ,Kilometraje varchar(20)   
                            ,Fuente varchar(250)
                            ,TipoDato varchar(150)
                            , Anioveh int
                            , Fecha datetime
                            , kilometros int
                            , KilometrajeDudoso int
                            , IdOrigen int
                            , AnioKilometraje int
                            , AutosNuevos int
                            )
    DECLARE 
        @id int

    DECLARE cursor_id CURSOR
    FOR SELECT id FROM tabla_de_donde_salen_los_ids;

    OPEN cursor_id;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_id INTO 
        @id;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            insert into @tabla SELECT *  FROM legaltec.dbo.fu_let_dv_robot_RevTecHistoriaDetalle(@id)

            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_id INTO 
                @id;
        END;

    CLOSE cursor_id;

    DEALLOCATE cursor_id;

 SELECT * FROM @tabla
```

ese cursor lo que hace es recorrer la consulta:

```
 SELECT id FROM tabla_de_donde_salen_los_ids;
```

y por cada id llama a la función e inserta el resultado en la tabla @tabla

ve probando esto y comenta tus dudas... intentaré estar pendiente hoy